# Who wrote the 1990's piece about the object oriented toaster?

Tags: electrical-engineering, software

In the 1990's (or earlier?), an unattributed piece was written about an electrical engineer and a software developer who were tasked with building a toaster. You can view the piece in its entirety [here](https://www.danielsen.com/jokes/objecttoaster.txt).

It is unattributed. No copies on the Internet that I've found reference the author.

Does anyone know who wrote this piece?

Below is a quote of its introduction:

> Once upon a time, in a kingdom not far from here, a king summoned two
> of his advisors for a test.  He showed them both a shiny metal box
> with two slots in the top, a control knob, and a lever.  "What do you
> think this is?"
>
> One advisor, an Electrical Engineer, answered first.  "It is a
> toaster," he said. The king asked, "How would you design an embedded
> computer for it?" The advisor: "Using a four-bit microcontroller, I
> would write a simple program that reads the darkness knob and
> quantifies its position to one of 16 shades of darkness, from snow
> white to coal black.  The program would use that darkness level as the
> index to a 16-element table of initial timer values.  Then it would
> turn on the heating elements and start the timer with the initial
> value selected from the table.  At the end of the time delay, it would
> turn off the heat and pop up the toast.  Come back next week, and I'll
> show you a working prototype."
>
> The second advisor, a software developer, immediately recognized the
> danger of such short-sighted thinking.  He said, "Toasters don't just
> turn bread into toast, they are also used to warm frozen waffles. What
> you see before you is really a breakfast food cooker.  As the subjects
> of your kingdom become more sophisticated, they will demand more
> capabilities.  They will need a breakfast food cooker that can also
> cook sausage, fry bacon, and make scrambled eggs.  A toaster that only
> makes toast will soon be obsolete.  If we don't look to the future, we
> will have to completely redesign the toaster in just a few years."

Comment: See Red Dwarf for the ultimate toaster design - the talking toaster...

Comment: Obviously an electrical engineer forced to work with a department of software developers.

Comment: Someone called Ian Chai posted the story to the mailing list<HUMOR@UGA.CC.UGA.EDU> on 27th April 1994, and even then, he claimed that the origin of the story was 'lost in the mists of time'.

Comment: ... and there's a [copy](https://www.glaver.org/ftp/humor/toaster-fable.txt) dated 9th December 1993 bearing the name "Lazar V. Mustur".

Comment: @DanielHatton Why don't you post it as a potential answer!

Answer (score 0):

It was published in a magazine about database programming and design circa 1992-3. I cannot remember the name of the author or the magazine. It is quite possibly my favorite article about programming. I kept a copy for years but sadly it has gone walkies. Given the period, the specification of "An Intel Pentium with 48MB of memory, a 1.2GB hard disk" was beyond the wildest dreams of all but the largest corporations, which made it that much more amusing and validated the king's wisdom.